# Git rebase: Combine non-subsequent commits

Tags: git, git-rebase

by now, I know that there is a nice way how to combine commits and change the commit message by using 'git rebase --interactive'

Having the following situation:

```
$ git rebase --interactive HEAD^^^^
pick 5b7c140 commitA
pick 40ffd7c commitB
pick 5e7647d commitC
pick 78bea2d commitD

Rebase [...]
```

Is there also a possibility to handle the following requirements:

Combining commitA and commitC and commitB and commitD to new commits cAC and cBD?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is possible - you can also rearrange the order of the commits with interactive rebase:

```
pick 5b7c140 commitA
squash 5e7647d commitC
pick 40ffd7c commitB
squash 78bea2d commitD
```

or

```
pick 5b7c140 commitA
fixup 5e7647d commitC
pick 40ffd7c commitB
fixup 78bea2d commitD
```

The difference between the two is that `squash` allows you to edit the commit message for the new commits, whereas `fixup` just throws away the second commit message leaving the preceeding `pick` commit message in place for the combined commit. (If your editor launches quickly enough, then having the habit of just choosing `squash` gives you a nice opportunity to review the commit message even if you think you would probably not need to use parts of the message of the `fixup` commit.)

Reordering the commits brings the possibility of conflicts during the rebase; in the example this would happen if `commitB` and `commitC` changed a same part of a file. This in mind, I often do this kind of rebase in two steps by first just reordering the commits to deal with the conflicts (in the example `pick` `A`, `C`, `B`, `D`) and then doing the commit combinations (`squash`, `fixup`). I find the conflict management becomes easier this way, especially if I am interrupted in the middle of doing this.

Comment: In my case: No conflicting files regarding these commits. Git is just great, thought I have to hold the commit order. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: The squash command will meld the given commit into the previous commit, so this example will actually affect the other commits that are still labeled as "pick". I just tried this and it certainly does not answer the question

Comment: @Flaom - I do not quite understand what's your issue. The `squash` solution I presented, as requested, will combine ("meld") together commits `commitA` and `commitC`, as well as combine commits `commitB` and `commitD` allowing you to edit the commit messages for the two resulting commits (using the original two squashed commits as reference when crafting the new commit message). If you have other (unsquashed and unfixupped) commits later or between and reordered, their hashes at least will change and, if these commits change the same files as the squashed commits, maybe their diffs as well.