# how to rebase 2 commits from 3

Tags: git, rebase

I have a doubt is there any way to rebase two commits, in the git log I have this:

```
9a0fcfab changes 3
6e04807a changes 2 
5cb49b8c changes 1
```

what I want is rebase 5cb49b8c and 9a0fcfab in 9a0fcfab and leave 6e04807a, something like:

```
pick 5cb49b8c changes 1
     6e04807a changes 2 <<<--- I want to omit this one
fixup 9a0fcfab changes 3
```

Comment: Re-order the lines and squash?

Comment: You want to _remove_ commit 6e04807a and _merge_  5cb49b8c and 9a0fcfab?

Comment: I want to merge 5cb49b8c and 9a0fcfab to have changes 1 and keep 6e04807a to have changes 2

Comment: Then do what Brian... said: re-order the lines and squash. And be careful how you speak. Don't say you want to "omit this one"; on the contrary, you want to _keep_ it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15406177/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-rebase%5D+combine+commits